# I am using PushBullet to send a message from Raspberry Pi. What should i enter as the host password in LXTerminal?

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, pushbullet

I am trying to send a push notification from Raspberry Pi to Pushbullet in Chrome PC from the [following resource](http://%20https://learnraspi.com/get-notifications-raspberry-pi-pushbullet/).

After typing the following commands, what should I enter when it asks for host password?

```
    sudo apt-get install curl
    curl -u [type your access code here] https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes/ -d type=note -d title="Raspberry Pi" body="Hello World!"
    Enter password for host:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try launching the command with elevated privilege

```
sudo curl -u [type your access code here] https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes/ -d type=note -d title="Raspberry Pi" body="Hello World!"`
```

alternatively you should write this to a .sh file ie a shell script and run it with elevated permissions as said in the [resource](https://learnraspi.com/get-notifications-raspberry-pi-pushbullet/) you provided.